# url rewrite in php using web.config

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

i want to rewrite this url "demo/demo/index.php" to "demo/demo/send.html" in php using web.config file.
I did this url rewrite by using htaccess file

Please somebody help me....

Comment: Show us your .htaccess and tell us what is or isn't working. Are you converting from .htaccess to web.config or vice versa?

Comment: vague questions lead to vague answers. You might want to put more effort on your side by properly writing the details to increase the odds of us writing detailed solutions too

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^demo/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?id=2
```

There really isn't much to go by from your question.